# Guest User not able to get data from custom object

Tags: community, force.com-sites, field-level-security, guest-user, digital-experience

I am having  simple custom object(Resources) with out any relation ship and having only one field (Resource Name)

I am trying to access the data inside this custom object through APEX and the user is guest user license.

Here is the list of settings I enabled so that guest user license profile can access the record

1. Went to the Guest user license profile and enbaled FLS to all the fields in the object
   [image]

2)Went to custom object permission and enabled create and read access
[image]

3)Went to sharing settings and enabled Public Read/Write to default external access
[image]

But still also not able to get records from this object but I have one record and here is the debug log
[image]

```
3:38:14.2 (7972335)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[19]|Aggregations:0|SELECT ResourceName__c FROM Resources__c
23:38:14.2 (40024754)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[19]|Rows:0
```

and My simple APEX code is

```
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)
    public static  List<Resources__c> searchDoctor(String searchStrng){    
        List<Resources__c> lstServiceResource= [SELECT ResourceName__c from Resources__c ];
            return lstServiceResource;
    }
```

PS:Enabled APEX class access for this Guest user profile also.

I am clueless on which setting still I have to enable . Need help on this.

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer. This [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnmK5qcSmhM) helped me
and  to be precise I created one dummy sharing rule for that custom object and shared to guest user as like the screen shot below
[image]

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Could you please enhance the answer with necessary detail so it isn't essentially just a link since these get broken over time and your answer will become useless to others if that happens here.

Comment: Sure @PhilW. Thanks

Comment: The 'dummy' sharing rule can be easily done as Id != blank